# including JSON into datatables plugin

Tags: json, datatables

i want to include my JSON list into table of datatables plugin, i have the code, but something is not working;/ maybe you will help :] I have the code which displays theader and build a table - it works fine , but something is wrong when i include the script into code;/ version of datatables 1.9.4

CODE:

```
  <html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/media/images/favicon.ico" />

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">

            @import "css/table.css";
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['numeric-comma-asc']  = function(a,b) {
                var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace( /,/, "." );
                var y = (b == "-") ? 0 : b.replace( /,/, "." );
                x = parseFloat( x );
                y = parseFloat( y );
                return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
            };

            jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['numeric-comma-desc'] = function(a,b) {
                var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace( /,/, "." );
                var y = (b == "-") ? 0 : b.replace( /,/, "." );
                x = parseFloat( x );
                y = parseFloat( y );
                return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "aoColumns": [
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
                        null
                    ]
                } );
            } );
        </script>













        <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    //code here
    var jsondata=$.parseJSON('{"response":[["name0","id0","amt0"],["name1","id1","amt1"]]}');

    $.each(jsondata.response, function(i, d) {
        var row='<tr>';
        $.each(d, function(j, e) {
             row+='<td>'+e+'</td>';
        });
        row+='</tr>';
        $('#example').append(row);
    });

});
        </script>
</head>


<body id="dt_example">


<div id="container">



            <div id="demo">


<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th></tr>
    </thead>

</table>
</div>




            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see a couple of problems, Looks like you are including jquery 1.4.2 first, and then including a different version later.  This probably isnt causing your problem, but it is a waste of time to add the resource and should be cleaned up.  I also noticed a ? character just before the close of your last script tag.  This could be causing your problems.

Comment: Well, i updated the code , and now  the rows are creating but not in the main table, just like the scripts are working in they own way or something ;/

Comment: This is because of the way you are calling the function with the body onload.  Pull the function call out of the body tag and put it before $('#example').datatable({

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: actually I dont think it will work calling that function inside of document.ready.  You can add it after you setup the functions like I did here:  http://jsfiddle.net/3FQB3/

Comment: Well thanks for help, but as you can see the result - "no data available in the table" it still didn't see the table ;/ also i checked on my code, and the same.. :(

Comment: well i think that library's are clashing, because i have a different code now and when i add latest jquerry library the script which create rows works, but datatables didn't and when i remove latest library , datatables start working but row creating function, not... ^^

Comment: I updated the code , now console is screaming that jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort is undefined.. ;/